# GraphQL: get prev / next entry from current entry (channel)

Tags: channels, queries, graphql

Is there a way to get the prev and next entry from the current entry, when this entry is inside a channel and not a structure?

```js
query ($id: [QueryArgument], $rel: Int) {
  entry: entry(id: $id) {
    id
    slug
    title
    uri
  }
  next: entry(nextSiblingOf: $rel) {
    id
    slug
    title
    uri
  }
  previous: entry(prevSiblingOf: $rel) {
    id
    slug
    title
    uri
  }
}
```

Output when the entry is in a structure:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "entry": {
      "id": "145",
      "slug": "neuigkeiten",
      "title": "Neuigkeiten",
      "uri": "neuigkeiten"
    },
    "next": {
      "id": "150",
      "slug": "leistungen",
      "title": "Leistungen",
      "uri": "leistungen"
    },
    "previous": {
      "id": "141",
      "slug": "unsere-praxis",
      "title": "Unsere Praxis",
      "uri": "unsere-praxis"
    }
  }
}
```

and the result when the entry is inside a channel:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "entry": {
      "id": "182",
      "slug": "david-hellmann-1-2",
      "title": "David Hellmann",
      "uri": "team/david-hellmann-1-2"
    },
    "next": null,
    "previous": null
  }
}
```

is there a way to get this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `next` and `prev` ([see documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/graphql.html#the-entryinterface-interface) and [this issue](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5571)).

```
query getEntryData($id: [QueryArgument]) {
  entry(id: $id) {
    id,
    slug,
    title,
    uri,
    prev(section: "blog", orderBy: "postDate desc") {
      id,
        slug,
        title,
        uri
    },
    next(section: "blog", orderBy: "postDate desc") {
      id,
        slug,
        title,
        uri
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @oli that means orderby id required here?